# Css nested counters with dinamic child element

Tags: css, css-counter

I use a css counters in nested menus.
And since chrome 65 strange bug started to happen.
Basically when a child menu items appears dinamically,
the counters starts leaking to a parent's sibling elements.

```
<style>
  ul {
    counter-reset: test;
  }

  ul li::before {
      counter-increment: test;
      content: counters(test, ".") " ";
  }
</style>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('submenu').style.display='none';">HIDE</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('submenu').style.display='block';">SHOW</button>

<ul>
  <li>aaaa
    <ul id="submenu" style="display:block;">
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>    
  </li>
  <li>bbbb</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ouvzhvd/14/

See a counter when opening page initialy, which is correct:
[image]

And this is how it looks when appeared dinamically (click hide -> show):
[image]

Anyone else experiencing this issue with latest chrome?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you just hit a Chrome bug, works fine on Firefox.

Comment: There is also a typo: last line `<ul>` should be `</ul>`.

Comment: @Stickers Thank you, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is Chrome Bug. Documented here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=822260
(which is how I found your post).